# Find DOM node given XML string representation of a node

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox, dom

For a particular node, I have an xml string stored in the database and it doesn't have an ID attribute.
e.g. `<H1 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Sample text here.</H1>`

I'm wondering how I could either create a DOM node or get the DOM node object based on this xml string.

Once I find this node, I need to manipulate it (hide it, etc.). I can't use DOMParser() to convert it into an object, since it just creates a stand along XMLDocument object.

Any ideas ?

Comment: yes, maybe.  But what are you really trying to do? Your q said "XML" but your example says "HTML".  Can you give some additional context to explain what your real goal is?

Comment: This is a FF extension which receives this xml string from XMLSerializer(). After receiving it needs to find this node to manipulate the node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new DOM node in the target document, call [adoptNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.adoptNode) to adopt the created node from the document created by DOMParser to the target one.

If you just want to find the node in a document, you'll have to walk the DOM tree and call isEqualNode on each node.

Comment: I want to find the existing node that is present in the document, and not insert a new one. Seems adoptNode adds a brand new one.

Comment: @PlanetUnknown Sorry, but wasn't that the question: "(...) either create a DOM node or get the DOM node object (..)". Anyway, appended the answer for a solution for *either* problem.

Comment: Thanks phihag 8-) walking the DOM tree was what I was trying to avoid.. But seems that is the only way. Need to jog my memory on tree traversal algorithms 8-)

Comment: @PlanetUnknown As I said, traversing should be fine. Since I don't actually have the setup for a Mozilla extension here, I dread writing traversal code that would not actually work. Basically, call a recursive traversal function that compares each node in the target document against `domParser(...).documentElement` and iterates over `childNodes` if available.